# Calculating optimal K value in K-means clustering with elbow curve

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I performed K-means clustering with a variety of k values and got the inertia of each k value (inertial being the sum of the standard deviation of all clusters, to my knowledge)

```
ks = range(1,30)
inertias = []
for k in ks:
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(trialsX)
    inertias.append(km.inertia_)
    
plt.plot(ks,inertias)
```

[image: inertia graph, which is an elbow plot]

Based on my reading, the optimal k value lies at the 'elbow' of this plot, but the calculation of the elbow has proven elusive. How can you programatically use this data to calculate k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post this, because it's the best I have come up with thus far:

It seems like using some threshold scaled to the range of the first derivative allong the curve might do a good job. This can be done by fitting a spline:

```
y_spl = UnivariateSpline(ks,inertias,s=0,k=4)
x_range = np.linspace(ks[0],ks[-1],1000)

y_spl_1d = y_spl.derivative(n=1)

plt.plot(x_range,y_spl_1d(x_range))
```

[image: first derivative of the inertia curve]

then, you can probably define k by, say 90% up this curve. I would imagine this is a pretty consistent way to do it, but there may be a better option.

EDIT: 2 years later,just use np.diff to generate this plot without fitting a spline, then find the point where the slope equals -1. See the comments for more info.

Comment: Could you please explain this in a little bit more detail. How do you find the optimal K from this graph?

Comment: It's been 2 years, and I posted this at the beginning of my data science career, but I'll do my best. Taking a step back, K is the number of groups you're creating in a K means cluster. Finding a K value means finding a good number of groups in a clustering problem. The inertia is a measure of the cumulative distance of all points to some center. As K goes up, you're creating more groups, and the inertia goes down.

Comment: A generally good K value is at the bend of this curve, which makes sense if you think about it. So, if you agree with that, the question has shifted from "what is a good k value" to "how do I detect the bend of this curve". I tried to do that by fitting a spline and taking the derivative, I guess? Not a good approach. now I would use np.diff to calculate the slope, at each point, then just find the point closest to a slope of -1 (where it's at a 45 degree angle). You could also calculate a different optimal slope if your curve has a strange shape, but 45 degrees is a good start.